# Python Pandas replace a cell containing a string with its above cell

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'm trying to replace a cell which contains certain string with its above cell:

Tried following code but it takes so long and cause error:

```
    row, col = df.shape
    for i in range(1,row):        
        if df.iloc[i,0] == "string": 
            df.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[i-1,0]
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general structure for these kind of problems is df.loc[cond, col] = ...

Using @meW's setup,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Elephant', 'Grass', 'Parameter', 'Root']})
df.loc[df.col.eq('Parameter'), 'col'] = df.col.shift(1)

    col
0   Elephant
1   Grass
2   Grass
3   Root
```

Comment: Thanks Vaishali, it looks good, though I used some other logic to work this out.